# Returning SQL data ordered by one column and grouped by another

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has the following simple schema:

```
Name | WorkingOn | Blockers | Completed | Date
---------------------------------------------------
Andy | Stuff     | Test     | test      | 2018-08-08 14:37:10.460
Andy | Dummy     | Test     | test      | 2018-08-09 14:37:10.460
Paul | Dummy     | Test     | test      | 2018-08-10 14:37:10.460
```

Every column is a `varchar` with the exception of Date which is a `datetime` value.

What I want to do is order my results by the newest date at top and to group everything by `Name`

I thought this could be done with the following SQL code:

```
SELECT  mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed, mt.Date
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
GROUP BY mt.Name
ORDER BY my.date DESC
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Column 'dbo.MyTable .WorkingOn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

What is it I need to change in order to get my results returning the way I want them to?

Comment: Please include your desired results.  The description is not sufficient.

Comment: Why are you grouping without aggregation? Do you not mean to use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions? What are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: Are you using `GROUP BY` in the SQL sense, or do you mean "I want all rows with the same name to appear *next to* the row that I've determined comes first by `Date`"?

Comment: Can you edit your question and say what you expect to get please? Grouping by name alone is not possible as each row in your table is currently unique. You should read more into what "Group by" actually does.

Comment: The GROUP BY statement takes all records with (in this case) the same name, and assumes you want to aggregate those by some criterion. This means you have to tell the query how the other columns should be aggregated. Examples of aggregations are SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, a.o. It looks like you are trying to achieve something else though.

Comment: This query will give unique row by name and records with latest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed, mt.Date
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
GROUP BY mt.Name, mt.Date, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed,
ORDER BY my.Date DESC
```

it should resolve the problem, as you need to put all the columns in Group by clause in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want the last row by date for an user, try this:

```
select * from (
select Name, WorkingOn, Blockers, Completed, Date,
row_number() over(partition by Name order by Date desc) rang
from yourtable
) tmp where tmp.rang=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description describes aggregation and ordering.  It would seem to describe this query:

```
SELECT mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed, MAX(mt.Date)
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
GROUP BY mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed
ORDER BY MAX(my.date) DESC
```

This aggregates the columns by name *and the other columns(, pulling out the max date.

I don't think that is what you want.  If you just want to order the rows, then this may be what you want:

```
select mt.*
from dbo.mytable mt
order by max(mt.date) over (partition by name), name, mt.date desc;
```

This orders the original rows by the maximum date for each name.  It keeps all rows, but groups the rows for a name together.

Or, perhaps aggregation has nothing to do with your question:

```
select top (1) with ties mt.*
from dbo.mytable mt
order by row_number() over (partition by name order by mt.date desc);
```

This keeps the most recent date for each name.

Answer (score 0):

**As per your requirement** -

```
SELECT  mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed, mt.Date
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
GROUP BY mt.Name, mt.WorkingOn, my.Blockers, mt.Completed, mt.Date
ORDER BY my.date DESC
```

Please [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for group by rules in SQL server